# How can I perform several counts and use the highest if they are all promises?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose, promise

Below is my controller for voting on a post.

If the user has not already voted on the post (their `voterId` is not present in the `votes` array). Then their `vote` is added by pushing their `voterId` into the `votes` array of the post. The `voteCount` is then reset to the `length` of that array.

There is some additional logic regarding sending Notifications to the `postAuthor`, but I have omitted that code so as to not obfuscate the issue.

Each `post` has an `expiresAt` timestamp. Each vote will give the `post` some more time to live (TTL), but HOW much time it will give will depend on which `category` that the post belongs to. Essentially, the more popular categories, such as music, will give less TTL than a less popular category, perhaps gardening.

So what I need to do is `count` how many `users` have the `category` as an interest. Based on that, I can calculate how much TTL to add.

The issue is that any post may have up to THREE categories. However many there are, I want to take the count of the MOST popular of the categories.

How can I do this? I was thinking of performing a `for loop` for each category that the `post` belongs to. Then taking the count, comparing with the last count, and assigning where necessary.

Of course, the problem with this is that each `Count`, returns a promise. So I'm assuming a `for loop` won't work.

Is there a logical solution to this? Thank you

```
  votePost(req, res, next) {
    const postId = req.params.id;
    const voterId = req.body.voterId;

      Post.findById(postId)
        .then(post => {
          // let followerCount;
          // let mostPopularCategoryFollowerCount = 0;
          //
          // // for (let i = 0; i < post.categories.length; i++) {
          // //   followerCount = User.count({ interests: { $eq: post.categories[i] } })
          // //     .then(count => count);
          // //
          // //     if (followerCount > mostPopularCategoryFollowerCount) {
          // //       mostPopularCategoryFollowerCount = followerCount;
          // //     }
          // // }

          if (post.votes.indexOf(voterId) === -1) {
            post.votes.push(voterId);
            post.voteCount = post.votes.length;

            // DO STUFF HERE WITH FOLLOWER COUNT //

              post.save()
                .then(() => res.send(post));
          }
        })
        .catch(next);
  },
```

Comment: Have your for loop push all the User.count() calls into an array. Feed that array into a `Promise.all()`, Once the Promise.all() resolves, you have all the categories and can put the follower count comparison in the callback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't a full implementation, just showing what I mean in my comment:

```
votePost(req, res, next) {
    const postId = req.params.id;
    const voterId = req.body.voterId;

    Post.findById(postId)
        .then(function( post ) {
            Promise.all(
                post.categories.map(function( category ) {
                    return User.count({ interests: { $eq: category } });
                })
            )
            .then(function( counts ) {
                return counts.reduce(function( highest, next ) {
                    return highest > next ? highest : next;
                }, 0);
            })
            .then(function( mostPopularCategoryFollowerCount ) {
                // do stuff with the count
            })
            .catch(function( err ) {
                // error handling
            });
        })
        .catch(next);
}
```